# Chrome onMessage.addListener executes only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a small question about javascript in my chrome extension. My popup window includes small form for searching books from one big site.
So when I search for book name, it should show loading spinner, send xhr request to the books API, remove the spinner, open options.html in a new tab and show the result. It works, but only sometimes.
So what do you suggest?

popup.js

```
// var books includes JSON array of fetched books
    hrome.tabs.create({url: "options.html"}, function(tab){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {booksList: books});
    });
```

And options.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 alert("OK");
});
```

But OK is shown only sometimes...Why?

Comment: I believe that domready sometimes runs too late. Either move `chrome.extension.onRequest` outside `$().ready`, or use the query string or URL fragment to pass data from the popup to the options page. An advantage of this method is that the user is also able to change the query by modifying the URL and/or bookmark the query.

Comment: Moving the listener outside of ready function is really good idea, but I want to manipulate with DOM at the same time. So how to do it?

Comment: You can move the logic inside the event listener to another function, then use a boolean flag and a domready event to call the function at the right time. Have you considered my other suggestion? That looks neater to me.

Comment: No, because I changed the code - it loads the json array of books and then opens options.html with the argument (json array). And I still have the issue with right timing.

Comment: Show the updated code, if relevant.

Comment: Tried this - http://pastie.org/4412482 or other combinations.

Comment: Something like this: http://pastie.org/4413504 (a quick write-up, I'm busy atm).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It still doesn't work. So I tried to alert something inside of the listener and this part works only sometimes. So the problem will be here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite busy atm. I suggest to edit your question to show what you currently have, so that others can help where you're stuck. When the question is edited, it also get bumped to the front page, increasing the likelihood that someone answers it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using localStorage...

popup.js

```
localStorage.books = JSON.stringify(books);
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "options.html"
}, function(tab) {
    console.log(books);
});​
```

options.js

```
var books = localStorage.books;
drawBooks(JSON.parse(books));
```

Comment: I suggest you either ellaborate on your own solution, or delete the question alltogether.